# The use of "it" and "they"

Tags: word-choice

I have been told by native speakers that "this", "that", "those", "these" are used in questions while "it" and "they" are used in anwers. As in "What is this?" "It's a book." Or "This is a book." "What are these?" "They are books." Or "These are books."
But in "English File" by Christina Latham-Koenig and Clive Oxenden I came across these examples: "What is it?" It's an umbrella." And "What are they?" "They are watches."
Could you please explain this use?

The only explanation the book gives is the difference between "this" and "that", and "those" and "these". It shows the objects near the speaker and and far from them.

The complete question were "What is it?" "It's ..."

The options were: "It's

a: an umbrella
b: a umbrella
c: umbrella

And "What are they?" "They are ..."

a: watches
b: a watch
c: watches

Comment: I have never heard of such a rule (for UK English). It might be that some of those words are more commonly used in questions and others more commonly in answers. But, as you shown in the question, there is no fixed rule.

Comment: Depending on the level of English File, it's possible the example are simplified to (it/they), as students haven't learned demonstrative pronouns (this, that, these, those) at that stage.

Comment: _This_ and _that_ are used when identifying the thing spoken about, whether or not the speaker is actually pointing to it. The person who answers can use _it_ because the thing has already been identified. But, as others have said, it isn't a fixed rule.

Comment: No, I am not talking about cases when "it" was used because the thing was already mentioned. I remember being corrected by a native speaker when I used "What is it"?  "It's a clock." I was told I should use "That/this" in my question.

Comment: No, the answer to *What is it?* doesn't necessarily starts with *that* or *this*. *It's a pen.* is also correct. The answer could also be *The cell phone I bought at Walmart.*

Comment: The native speaker told me I should start my sentence with "this" or "that" and use "it" and "they" in answrs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no rule like that. You can demonstrate it by common counterexamples:

"Which would you like?" - the wizard asked.

"I want **that**." - the cat said, pointing its tail at a large ornate book.

"It's pretty expensive and much too heavy. Are you sure you want **it**?"

Thinking it over, the cat pointed to three smaller scroll: "Alright then, I choose **those**."